# how to zoom into a location by using click button in Angular

Tags: angular, openlayers, angular-openlayers

I would like to `zoom` in `openlayers` library to a location eg: `Berlin` when the user click on the button. can someone tell me how is it possible to be done?

Below are my code:

#### app.component.html

```
<button id='berlin' (click)="onClick('berlin')">Zoom to Berlin</button>
```

#### app.component.ts

```
berlin = fromLonLat([13.388866, 52.517071]);

public onClick(city:any) {
   console.log(city);
   view.animate({
      center: city,
      duration: 2000
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var bern = ol.proj.transform([7.4458,46.95], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'); 
document.getElementById ("berlin").addEventListener ("click", berlinZoom, false);
 function berlinZoom() {

            var bernview = new ol.View({
                center: bern,
                zoom: 6
            });  
         map.setView(bernview); 
        }
```

Comment: for the animation you need to do this map.getView()..animate({
           center: bern,
                zoom: 6,
          duration: 2000
        });

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string, here: `'berlin'`, to your function `onClick`, therefore it looks like this:

```
view.animate({
  center: 'berlin',
  duration: 2000
});
```

I guess, you would like to jump to `[13.388866, 52.517071]`. This should do the trick:

```
coords = {
   berlin: [13.388866, 52.517071],
   // Add other cities
   ...
};

onClick (city: string) {
   view.animate({
      center: fromLonLat(coords[city]),
      duration: 2000
   });
}
```

Comment: i got an error as below:

AppComponent.html:46 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of undefined

Comment: Looks like your `view` is undefined. Is `view` of type [`ol/view`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html) and how do you pass it to your component? Even better would be something like `map.getView().animate(...);`